# Can I run a MIDlet on an iPhone 4s?

Tags: java, iphone, ios, netbeans, midlet

I'm trying to make a simple application similar to the commonly used "Hello World" using Netbeans 7.2 for a project at school. I'm just wondering if I could run it on an iPhone 4s? If not, would a Samsung GT-15503 work (I initially planned on making an Android app but it's not working too well for me)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS does not have a Java implementation so no, your app will not run on an iPhone 4S. As far as I know, the Samsung will not run a straight MIDlet either. You're best off looking at developer.android.com for a guide on how to start Android development.